# My .pug view not working in Sails and Node JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pug

I'm trying to render a `.pug` view in my App developed in Node.js with Sails but it's just showing code in my browser. I have reconfigured my `config/views.js` like this

```
module.exports.views = {
    extension: 'pug',
    getRenderFn: function () {
        let consolidate = require('consolidate');
        return consolidate.pug;
    },
    layout: false
};
```

Finally this is the result [My .pug Code in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU8WQ.png)

Comment: I'd give up on that approach. In my experience the best way to go about using pug is to first go with jade `sails new projectname --template=jade`. Then alter config/views.js setting `engine: 'pug'`. Finally, change any view using .jade to .pug.